# How to apply discount based on checkout page form fill up

Tags: wordpress

I have developed an eCommerce site based on a Wocommerce theme. I have only one product. I am trying to apply a 10% discount if anyone just fills up/answers some certain form fields of questions in the checkout page. I need to grab those important answer hence offering a 10% discount.
Now my question is how can I achieve the checkout page form customization and apply discount conditionally on the checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way that come in my mind is this:

- create a one time use per user coupon code
- ask the user to fill the form
- after the form is submitted print the coupon code

**Extra:**

If you want you can have an **exclusive coupon for every single user**, to do this create a coupon programmatically and limit the use (only one time)
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-coupon-programatically/#

Is it possibile to grow in complexity by **programmatically apply coupon in cart**, here a little example that need to be customized to fit your needs:
https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-apply-coupon-programmatically-product-cart/

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but you can do it like this:

1 - Write a PHP function and add filter for it with woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form hook

2 - Add the questions to the checkout form with relevant input fields

3 - Assign unique id and onchange attributes to those input fields

4 - Write a JS function inside the PHP function to check if those fields are filled before submission (onchange functions)

5 - If yes, return the total value with 10% discount using woocommerce_calculate_totals hook and a simple PHP function for 10% discount

I hope it works, if you need more help I can try these after several hours and post the results.